# webform 5 access other webform tokens

Tags: webforms, tokens

Is there a way to access tokens of another webform ? I have users of one role who need to evaluate in a webform files uploaded by users with another webform

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported and could be a security issue because it would allow people to use tokens to pry into information available in other entities.